# Zoom based on cursor using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've both tried to solve the problem as well as search StackOverflow for multiple solutions, none that seemed to work properly. I have what appears to be a close but not quite the end result I'm looking for. I'm trying to make it so when the user zooms using the mousewheel, the zoom being based on the cursor's position.

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong here. Somewhere in my calculation for the image offset im doing something wrong which you'll see when you test it.

```
 // offset image based on cursor position
  var width = img_ele.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  var height = img_ele.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  var x_cursor = window.event.clientX;
  var y_cursor = window.event.clientY;
  var x = img_ele.offsetLeft;
  var y = img_ele.offsetTop;

  // Calculate displacement of zooming position.
  var dx = x - ((x_cursor - x) * (factor - 1.0));
  var dy = y - ((y_cursor - y) * (factor - 1.0));

  img_ele.style.left = dx + 'px';
  img_ele.style.top = dy + 'px';
```

Below is the full code. Just change the src image to one of your liking.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <img ondragstart="return false" id="drag-img" src="map.jpg" />
</div>
<input type="button" id="zoomout" class="button" value="Zoom out">
<input type="button" id="zoomin" class="button" value="Zoom in">
<input type="button" id="zoomfit" class="button" value="Zoom fit">
</body>
</html>
<script>


var img_ele = null,
  x_cursor = 0,
  y_cursor = 0,
  x_img_ele = 0,
  y_img_ele = 0;

function zoom(factor) {
  img_ele = document.getElementById('drag-img');

  // Zoom into the image.
  var width = img_ele.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  var height = img_ele.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  img_ele.style.width = (width * factor) + 'px';
  img_ele.style.height = (height * factor) + 'px';

  // offset image based on cursor position
  var width = img_ele.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  var height = img_ele.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  var x_cursor = window.event.clientX;
  var y_cursor = window.event.clientY;
  var x = img_ele.offsetLeft;
  var y = img_ele.offsetTop;

  // Calculate displacement of zooming position.
  var dx = x - ((x_cursor - x) * (factor - 1.0));
  var dy = y - ((y_cursor - y) * (factor - 1.0));

  img_ele.style.left = dx + 'px';
  img_ele.style.top = dy + 'px';

  console.log('MAP SIZE : ' + width, height);
  console.log('MAP TOP/LEFT : ' + x, y, 'NEW:', dx, dy);
  console.log('CURSOR : ' + x_cursor, y_cursor);
  img_ele = null;

}

function zoom_fit() {
  bb_el = document.getElementById('container')
  img_el = document.getElementById('drag-img');

  var width = bb_el.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  var height = bb_el.getBoundingClientRect().height;

  img_el.style.width = width + 'px';
  img_el.style.height = height + 'px';
  img_el.style.left = '0px';
  img_el.style.top = '0px';
  img_el = null;
}

document.getElementById('zoomout').addEventListener('click', function() {
  zoom(0.9);
});
document.getElementById('zoomin').addEventListener('click', function() {
  zoom(1.1);
});
document.getElementById('zoomfit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  zoom_fit();
});
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  x_cursor = window.event.clientX;
  y_cursor = window.event.clientY;
  // console.log('ZOOM : ' + 'X:', x_cursor, 'Y:', y_cursor);

  if (event.deltaY < 0) {
    // console.log('scrolling up');
    zoom(1.1);
  }
  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    // console.log('scrolling down');
    zoom(0.9);
  }
});

function start_drag() {
  img_ele = this;
  // console.log('inside start_drag var img_ele set to : ' + this);
  x_img_ele = window.event.clientX - document.getElementById('drag-img').offsetLeft;
  y_img_ele = window.event.clientY - document.getElementById('drag-img').offsetTop;
  // console.log('start_drag : ' + 'x_img_ele:', x_img_ele, 'y_img_ele:', y_img_ele);
}

function stop_drag() {
// console.log('stop drag');
  img_ele = null;
}

function while_drag() {
  // console.log('while_drag: ', window.event);
  var x_cursor = window.event.clientX;
  var y_cursor = window.event.clientY;
  if (img_ele !== null) {
    img_ele.style.left = (x_cursor - x_img_ele) + 'px';
    img_ele.style.top = ( window.event.clientY - y_img_ele) + 'px';

    // console.log('while_drag: ','x_cursor', x_cursor, 'x_img_ele', x_img_ele, 'y_cursor', y_cursor, 'y_img_ele', y_img_ele,'Image left and top', img_ele.style.left+' - '+img_ele.style.top);
  }
}

document.getElementById('drag-img').addEventListener('mousedown', start_drag);
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('mousemove', while_drag);
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('mouseup', stop_drag);
function while_drag() {
  var x_cursor = window.event.clientX;
  var y_cursor = window.event.clientY;
  if (img_ele !== null) {
    img_ele.style.left = (x_cursor - x_img_ele) + 'px';
    img_ele.style.top = ( window.event.clientY - y_img_ele) + 'px';
    // console.log(img_ele.style.left+' - '+img_ele.style.top);
  }
}

document.getElementById('drag-img').addEventListener('mousedown', start_drag);
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('mousemove', while_drag);
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('mouseup', stop_drag);
</script>

<style>
#drag-img {
  cursor: move;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 25px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: a couple of logic mistakes here, you're zooming relative to the mouse, which will be doing when you just click on the zoomin and zoom out even tho the mouse isn't on the img, second your zoom function isn't backward compatible you'll zoomin just fine from the start but not vice versa, i would suggest you limite the zoom out to the container, that way it'll be much simpler.

Comment: The buttons i will eventually get rid of and just use the mouse wheel. This doesn't help me resolve the ultimate issue of the zooming about the cursor

Comment: Yeah, like i said you need to limite the zoomout to the container, then redo your logic, that zoom function isn't backward compatible, i doubt anyone would want to go through the headache of figuring out the logic for you, your codes it just needs tweaking for your desired result, and this isn't the right website to post that issue since it works.